# How to compare a string to a cs from a read properly?

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox, strings, xstring

The scenario: reading a date in a `yyyy-mm-dd` form from a file to a cs. This  cs later gets compared to a 'current date' macro to write a few args in a specific way to an external file. The current day macro is along the lines of

```
% \def\TODAY{}
% \def\Today{\the\year-\TwoDigits{\the\month}-\TwoDigits{\the\day} }
\def\TODAY{\xdef\Today{\the\year-\TwoDigits{\the\month}-\TwoDigits{\the\day}}}
```

This works for the labeling things, since `\ref{yyyy-mm-dd}` works as intended. Having no extra `\TODAY` and then using `\def`'d Today does so to, it's the comparison that's not working. `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrequal` is not what I used before. Whenever the date would change  I used a single `\xdef` and later passed that macro to a `\ifx`, and to get it to work I had to define the date with a  appended. *edit* Read to my amazement inserts a single space after whatever's been read.

Currently I'm supposedly fixing things, but I broke it somehow, and now it doesn't match at all. The first culprit was the my `\TwoDigits` cmd was robust, changing it back to `\def` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` fixed that. The latter is for user-level commands, so I'll let that slip. But the results of the mwe are not clear to me.

`0.txt` contains one line with `2001-01-01` and a line new afterwards, as if one line had been written to it and the output had been closed.

The questions:

1. What the 'right' way to compare things (macro, cs, command?) are that (should) expand to strings?
2. Why don't `\edef`, `\xdef` work here, I thought it was a full expansion, and indeed before (my version control is nigh absent so I can't give a mwe for this)  it worked.
3. What is the significance of robustness? Is there a simple rule of thumb when it's necessary, obligatory, or irrelevant?
4. It working with `xstring`'s `\IfStrEqual` *only* if the  is inserted in the definition of `\datemacro`, rather than in the comparison's brackets, i.e., `{\datemacro }`. Why?
5. `\ifstrequal` supposedly doesn't expand- I used once in a command to test if an arguments is equal to `&`, this works- is #1 becoming whatever was input not count as an expansion?

*edit*: I forgot `\ifx` was used for macros, not delimited arguments, sorry.

example 1;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=0.6cm, hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newread\periods
\openin\periods=0.txt
\begin{document}\setlength\parindent{0pt}\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont
\def\testi{2001-01-01}
\edef\testii{2001-01-01}
\def\testiii{2001-01-01 }
\edef\testiiii{2001-01-01 }
\global\read\periods to \DDD

\ifstrequal{\testi}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testii}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiii}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiiii}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\DDD}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F

\ifstrequal{\testi}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\DDD}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T

\ifx{\testi}{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\testii}{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\testiii}{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\testiiii}{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\DDD}{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F

\ifx{\testi}{\DDD} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\testii}{\DDD} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\testiii}{\DDD} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\testiiii}{\DDD} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx{\DDD}{\DDD} T\\\else F\\\fi% F

\ifcsequal{\testi}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\testii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\testiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\testiiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\DDD}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F

\ifdefequal{\testi}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifdefequal{\testii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifdefequal{\testiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T
\ifdefequal{\testiiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T
\ifdefequal{\DDD}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T
\end{document}
```

example 2;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=0.6cm, hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring}
\def\TwoDigits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0#1\else#1\fi}

\newcount\month
    \month 1\relax
\newcount\day
    \day 1\relax
\newread\periods
\openin\periods=0.txt
\global\read\periods to \DDD

\def\testi{2001-\TwoDigits{\the\month}-\TwoDigits{\the\day}}%
\edef\testii{2001-\TwoDigits{\the\month}-\TwoDigits{\the\day}}%
\def\testiii{2001-\TwoDigits{\the\month}-\TwoDigits{\the\day} }%
\edef\testiiii{2001-\TwoDigits{\the\month}-\TwoDigits{\the\day} }%

\begin{document}\setlength\parindent{0pt}
DDD is \DDD.% space between cs and .

\ifstrequal{\testi}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testii}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiii}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiiii}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\DDD}{2001-01-01}{T\\}{F\\}% F

\ifstrequal{\testi}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\testiiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifstrequal{\DDD}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T

\ifx\testi{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx\testii{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx\testiii{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx\testiiii{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx\DDD{2001-01-01} T\\\else F\\\fi% F

\ifx\testi\DDD T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx\testii\DDD T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx\testiii\DDD T\\\else F\\\fi% F
\ifx\testiiii\DDD T\\\else F\\\fi% T
\ifx\DDD\DDD T\\\else F\\\fi% T

\ifcsequal{\testi}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\testii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\testiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\testiiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifcsequal{\DDD}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F

\ifdefequal{\testi}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifdefequal{\testii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifdefequal{\testiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\ifdefequal{\testiiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T
\ifdefequal{\DDD}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T

\IfStrEq{\testi}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\IfStrEq{\testii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\IfStrEq{\testi }{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\IfStrEq{\testii }{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% F
\IfStrEq{\testiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T
\IfStrEq{\testiiii}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T
\IfStrEq{\DDD}{\DDD}{T\\}{F\\}% T

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ifx{\testi}...` compares `{` with `\testi`. Be careful with primitive TeX conditionals.

Answer (score 4):

### `\ifstrequal`

From the documentation of `etoolbox`:

> `\ifstrequal{⟨string⟩}{⟨string⟩}{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`
>   Compares two strings and executes ⟨true⟩ if they are equal, and ⟨false⟩ otherwise. The strings are not expanded in the test and the comparison is category code agnos- tic. Control sequence tokens in any of the ⟨string⟩ arguments will be detokenized and treated as strings. This command is robust.

Therefore `\ifstrequal{\testi}{...}` won't return true unless `...` is exactly the same as `\testi` *as strings*.

On the other hand,

```latex
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\DDD}{2001-01-01 }{T}{F}
```

will return `T`, but notice the traling space, which is generated by `\read` seeing an end-of-line.

### `\ifx`

This is a primitive conditional and should be used with its proper syntax: `\ifx AB` compares the tokens `A` and `B` without expansion. So `\ifx{\DDD}...` will compare `{` with `\DDD`.

### `\ifcsequal`

> `\ifcsequal{⟨csname⟩}{⟨csname⟩}{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`
>   Similar to `\ifdefequal` except that it takes control sequence names as arguments.

Thus `\ifcsequal{\testi}{\DDD}` will expand both `\testi` and `\DDD`, so it is the same as doing `\ifcsequal{2001-01-01}{2001-01-01 }` which returns false because the two built control sequences are both equivalent to `\relax`.

### `\ifdefequal`

This is where you finally get the code to return true. Note that if you use

```
\def\testiii{2001-\TwoDigits{\the\month}-\TwoDigits{\the\day} }%
```

then `\ifdefequal{\testiii}{\DDD}` will return *false*, because it just looks at the first level expansion. On the other hand, the `\edef` version is what works.

### `\IfStrEq`

This does full expansion of its arguments (under normal conditions), so the comparison with either `\testiiii` or `\testiiii` works.

### Robustness

The robustness of `\ifstrequal` is completely irrelevant. Well, not completely, actually. If your TeX engine supports `\expanded` (all will in a few weeks, with the release of TeX Live 2019), something like

```
\expanded{\ifstrequal}{\testiii}{\DDD}{T}{F}}
```

will return `T` and robustness of `\ifstrequal` is decisive for this to work.

Use the working test.

Comment: What exactly does it mean for a control sequence to be equivalent to `\relax`, given that `\ifcsequal{\relax}{\relax}{T}{F}` doesn't wants an `endcsname`? The robustness question is probably most important, because it's not straightforward to understand where it's important- like mentioned above, if `\TwoDigits` was declared via`xparse`, it doesn't work in my code, cannot guarantee for the 2. given example.